# jQuery if statement $(this) selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I 'select' the dom elements that pass the if statement in jQuery?

I am checking if the url has a hash. The hash matches the video container's class. If the url does have a hash, the iframe with the matching class gets an active class added to display it as block, instead of hidden. If it doesn't, the first video in the list is displayed:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    videoCarousel();

}); 

function videoCarousel() {

    // Set variables
    var carousel = $('#video_container');
    var videos = $('#video_container #video iframe');

    // Get url hash and remove # from begining
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);


    if (videos.hasClass(hash)) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        videos.first().addClass('active');
    }

}
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell without a lot more context whether that is the right code or the wrong code.  Please post a bit more of your script, and some of your HTML as well.

Comment: The if statement is correct, i think the problem is with your `$(this)`. By `$(this)` if you mean `$('div')`, it won't work. You would have to use `$('div')`.

Comment: You really don't need an `if`. Look at @Neysor's and @JNF's answer

Comment: The edit is good, but it's still unclear why you're using `this`. In JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by how a function is called, so if you really mean to be using `this`, you need to tell us how `videoCarousel` is called. (I suspect you don't want `this`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the function is being called on document load.

Comment: Still hard to tell whether you really mean to bind to `$(this)` or not.  However you should look into the [jQuery class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is the only JS I have on the page. I want the 'active' class to be added to the iframe with the matching class of the hash in the url, if there is a match.

Comment: @theorise: I figured it out, I think a lot of us were reading past some of the initial paragraph. Added an answer I think does what you want.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! I thought the question was a lot more basic originally. I didn't expect so much context to be needed to make the question make sense!

Comment: @theorise: Glad that helped. Yeah, we needed the info from your first edit, but after that it was a matter of us just not reading what you'd written thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the url does have a **hash**, the iframe **with the matching class** gets an active class added to display it as block, instead of hidden. If it doesn't, the first video in the list is displayed:

*(My emphasis)*

That's the key info, and I think a lot of us read past it. You need to change your selector, and you don't want `this` at all:

```
function videoCarousel() {
    // Set variables
    var carousel = $('#video_container');
    var videos = $('#video_container #video iframe');

    // Get url hash and remove # from begining
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    // Get the video with the matching class
    var targetVideo;
    if (hash) {
        targetVideo = videos.filter("." + hash);
    }
    if (!targetVideo || !targetVideo[0]) {
        // There's no hash, or no match; use the first
        targetVideo = videos.first();
    }

    // Add the class
    targetVideo.addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct way to use Jquery would be:

```
$('div.video').addClass('active');
```

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: *"This will blow up with null reference exceptions if there isn't a div with that class..."* No it won't. This is one of the big things about jQuery, it's set-based. So if there's no `div.video`, you get back an empty jQuery object (an empty set), not `null`. You can call `addClass` on an empty jQuery object. It's totally fine, it ends up being a no-op.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: No. jQuery has been set-based since v1.0: http://jsbin.com/azumaw

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Aha.  I just found out I've been using some old hairy version of prototype and I just assumed it was some old hairy version of jQuery.  Thanks for challenging my assumptions.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Ah! Yes, Prototype is not set-based. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but are you looking for this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/JD37S/)**

```
$("div.video").each(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

**because of your edit**

think you could want to have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    videoCarousel();

}); 

function videoCarousel() {

    // Set variables
    var carousel = $('#video_container');
    var videos = $('#video_container #video iframe');

    // Get url hash and remove # from begining
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    var hasone = false;
    videos.each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass(hash)) {
        $(this).addclass("active");
        hasone = true;
        return false; //breaks each();
      }
    });
    if(!hasone) {
      videos.first().addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between `div` and `.video`. The fiddle is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
function videoCarousel() {

    // Set variables
    var carousel = $('#video_container');
    var videos = $('#video_container #video iframe');

    // Get url hash and remove # from begining
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    //Filter out the element that match the hash or is the first video in the collection
    var activeVideo = videos.filter(function(i) {
        return hash === "" ? i === 0 : $(this).hasClass(hash);
    });

    activeVideo.addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try it like this:

```
function videoCarousel() {

// Set variables
var carousel = $('#video_container');
var videos = $('#video_container #video iframe');

// Get url hash and remove # from begining
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);


$(".yourClass").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass(hash)) {  
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
    } else {
        videos.first().addClass("active");
    });
});
}
```